# Cloud firestore and nextjs - getInitialProps and async data

Tags: async-await, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

Im attempting to retrieve a document using the getInitialProps method from nextjs. However it is returning a Promise with a state 'pending'. Here is my code:

```
  static async getInitialProps(context) {
    const { id } = context.query;

    await db
      .collection('clients')
      .doc('JJqyDI8a1ILqnqmp2gcO')
      .get()
      .then(doc => ({
        data: doc.data(),
      }));

    console.log(data); // logs pending

    return {
      client: data,
    };
  }
```

I cant seem to find any examples either.

Answer (score 0):

All async functions return a promise.

I don't see how you're accessing `data` because when you console.log it is already out of scope.

Do something like this:

```
  static async getInitialProps(context) {
    const { id } = context.query;

    const data = await db
      .collection('clients')
      .doc('JJqyDI8a1ILqnqmp2gcO')
      .get()
      .then(doc => ({
        ...doc.data(),
      }));


    return {
      client: data,
    };
  }
```

This should make it accessible by `props.client`